# Question on norm on Sobolev Space

Tags: sobolev-spaces

If $u\in W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ we define its norm as
$$
\Vert u \Vert_{W^{k,p}(\Omega)}=
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle
\left(\sum_{|\alpha|\le k}\displaystyle\int\limits_\Omega |D^\alpha u|^p\mathrm{d}x\right)^\frac{1}{p} & 1\le p <\infty,\\
\\
\:\:\displaystyle\sum_{|\alpha|\le k} \underset{\Omega}{\mathrm{ess\,sup}}|D^\alpha u| & p=\infty
\end{cases}
$$

Are these the only norms on a Sobolev space... and how can we say that these norms exists on this space?

Answer (score 0):

There are other equivalents norm as for example $$\|u\|_{W^{k,p}}=\sum_{|\alpha |\leq k}\|D^\alpha u\|_{L^p}$$
or $$\|u\|_{W^{k,p}}^p=\sum_{|\alpha |\leq k}\|D^\alpha u\|_{L^p}^p.$$

For the existence, what do you mean ? $\|\cdot \|_{W^{k,p}}$ is a norm on $W^{k,p}$, so it exist !

Comment: @surb....i mean we define some norms is those are well defined

Comment: @InverseProblem: What do you mean by "well defined" ? That $\|u\|_{W^{k,p}}<\infty $ ? If yes, then it's well defined on $W^{k,p}$ by definition of $W^{k,p}$.